# Is there a way to view changes in Azure Data Factory before saving them in DevOps GIT?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm new to the Azure Data Factory Web UI. My current project is set to use Azure DevOps GIT. Occasionally, I'll be experimenting and open and close several pipelines and datasets and suddenly notice the Author tab (in the left hand panel) has a yellow circle overlay displaying a number on the pencil icon. I assume this is the number of changes I've made to the project; If the pipeline that I've changed is still open, it will show a dot in the tab next to it's name and when I save it, the number in the overlay decrements.

But sometimes, I can close/save all the objects and  still see the overlay on the pencil icon. In this case, if I try to close the project (or switch branches) I'll get a message asking if I want to save my changes. At this point, I don't know what I've changed so I'm not sure what changes will be lost. If I save my changes, the changes are automatically committed (that's an annoyance). To view the changes, I create a pull request (assuming I'm working on a branch) and review all the changes since branch was created (another annoyance).

Is there a way to see my changes before saving? and is there a way to save changes before committing them?

Comment: I just realized that some changes I make to objects in the GUI may propagate to other objects causing the number of changes to increment without the object being displayed in the pipeline designer panel. However, if I expand the list of objects in the Factory Resources panel, the object changed will have a dot displayed to the left of its name. While this shows which object (json file) was changed, there is still no way to see what was changed prior to saving/committing.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?  It's frustrating that it tells you that a change has been made, but not what was changed.

Comment: Not really; you can clone the repo to your local machine before you make changes and then copy the 'changed' JSON code to a file and do a diff. Or you can open the 'changed' object in ADF and then close it without saving - often I've seen the 'change' is just a reordering of the lines in the JSON file.